# Prepend uppercase chars with underscores in a string

Tags: php

I am trying to convert a string e.g. `WhatAWonderfulDay` into a lowercase string where all uppercase characters are preceded with underscores e.g. `what_a_wonderful_day`. Also, I am trying to make a reverse algorithm that translates let's say `a_quick_fox` into `AQuickFox`.

I am providing my implementation, though I know it's inefficient. Any ways to simplify these two operations?

```
// 1. WhatAWonderfulDay -> what_a_wonderful_day

$chars = str_split('WhatAWonderfulDay');
$result = "";
foreach($chars as $char) {
    if (ctype_upper($char) && !empty($result))
        $result .= "_"
    $result .= $char;
}
echo $result;

// 2. a_quick_fox => AQuickFox

$chars = str_split('a_quick_fox');

$result = "";
$should_make_upper = true;
foreach($chars as $char) {
    $result .= (should_make_upper) ? strtoupper($char) : $char;
    $should_make_upper = false;
    if ($char == "_")
        $should_make_upper = true;
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: This is best done with regexes

Comment: @user3791775 True, but could you elaborate?

Comment: Use `preg_replace` with a regex to select only the Uppercase letters. You should check the docs of [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some simpel code that will get you started:

```
$string = "AQuickTest";

preg_match_all("/[A-Z]/",$string,$matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $match){
    $string = str_replace($match,"_".strtolower($match),$string);
}

echo $string;
```

The result is: `_a_quick_test`

Answer (score 0):

I got a working solution using some basic regex.

To add underscores to a piece of text, use:

```php
function addUnderscores($chars) {
    return strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<!^)[A-Z]/', '_\\0', $chars));
}

echo addUnderscores('WhatAWonderfulDay'); // Outputs "what_a_wonderful_day"
```

To remove them, use

```php
function removeUnderscores($chars) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/^\w|_(\\w)/', function ($matches) {
        return strtoupper((sizeof($matches)==2)?$matches[1]:$matches[0]);
    }, $chars);
}

echo removeUnderscores('a_quick_fox'); // Outputs "AQuickFox"
```

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a5a630eb666a86f498847cb61d1f89b188ed861f)